# Idempotents in centralizers of non-nilpotent zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, idempotents, artinian

Let $R$ be a (say left-right-Artinian) noncommutative unital ring and $r \in R$ a non-nilpotent zero divisor. Does there necessarily exist a nontrivial idempotent $e$ that commutes with $r$?

This holds in any periodic ring. The "non-nilpotent" condition is to avoid the local rings.